# Column 'objectId' does not exist Exception (only in emulator)

Tags: android, database

I have a really strange issue with my application and I don't know why it's happening (only in emulator). I'm using a custom database helper class and I don't have any problems with it. But I have an issue with a specific column in a database table which I'm using really often. So depending on a some `extras` which I send from a parent activity I'm running different sql statements. Here is what I'm using :

```
String sql = "";
    switch (sort) {
    case 1:
            if (extra != 0) {
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT c.objectId FROM cards AS c "
                        + "INNER JOIN cardtags AS ct "
                        + "ON (c.objectId=ct.cardId) "
                        + "WHERE c.collectionId=" 
                        + collId 
                        + " AND c.repeatsCount>0"+ " AND ct.tagId="
                        + extra;

            } else if (extra == 0) {
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT c.objectId FROM cards AS c "
                        + "INNER JOIN cardtags AS ct "
                        + "ON (c.objectId=ct.cardId) "
                        + "WHERE c.collectionId=" 
                        + collId 
                        + " AND c.repeatsCount>0";
            }
        break;
    case 2:
            if (extra != 0) {
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cd.objectId FROM cards AS cd "
                        + "INNER JOIN categories AS ct "
                        + "ON (cd.categoryId=ct.objectId) "
                        + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" 
                        + collId
                        + " AND ct.objectId=" 
                        + extra 
                        + " AND cd.repeatsCount>0";

            } else if (extra == 0) {
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cd.objectId FROM cards AS cd "
                        + "INNER JOIN categories AS ct "
                        + "ON (cd.categoryId=ct.objectId) "
                        + "WHERE cd.collectionId=" 
                        + collId 
                        + " AND cd.repeatsCount>0";
            }
        break;
    case 3:
            String AscDesc = "";
            if (ascDesc == 0) {
                AscDesc = "ASC";
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT objectId FROM cards "
                        + "WHERE collectionId="
                        + collId 
                        + " AND repeatsCount>0"
                        + " ORDER BY dateCreated "
                        + AscDesc;

            } else if (ascDesc != 0) {
                AscDesc = "DESC";
                sql = "SELECT DISTINCT objectId FROM cards  "
                        + "WHERE collectionId="
                        + collId 
                        + " AND repeatsCount>0"
                        + " ORDER BY dateCreated "
                        + AscDesc;
            }
        break;
    }
    Cursor myCursor = userDbHelper.executeSQLQuery(sql);
    if (myCursor.getCount() == 0) {
        myCursor.close();
    } else if (myCursor.getCount() > 0) {
        myCardID = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        myCardID.clear();
        for (myCursor.move(0); myCursor.moveToNext(); myCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            int cardId1 = myCursor.getInt(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("objectId"));
            myCardID.add(cardId1);
        }
    }
```

When I try to start this activity it's throwing me an exception (ONLY IN EMULATOR,on real device - HTC Desire, HTC EVO 3D there is no problem)

`"11-30 14:51:18.899: E/AndroidRuntime(14818): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'objectId' does not exist"`

on line : `int cardId1 = myCursor.getInt(myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("objectId"));`

But the strange things is that when I download the database file from the emulator and open it, I can see clearly that I have column `objectId` there and I'm using that column in other files too, but it's not throwing me an exception. So I'm wondering is it some kind of emulator bug, because I don't get anything like this on device or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried recreating / upgrading the database?

Comment: I'm creating database in every application start and I can see that there is column `objectId` when I look at sqlite file.

Comment: have you tried enumerating the column names to see what you actually got in the cursor? could objectId be called 'c.objectId' in some cases?

Comment: onCreate event is ONLY Called when the database is created for the first time NOT always, so you can try uninstalling the application from the emulator & then reinstall it.

Comment: in some cases I'm using c.objectId but it's not showing an error on device and as far as I know it shouldn't throw an exception there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the alias for the column in the select statement. Only in case 3 does your cursor actually contain a column called objectId so when you do `myCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("objectId")` it throws an exception.

In case 1 the column in the cursor is "c" and in case 2 it is "cards".